# wordpress Website not showing cloudflare cdn

Tags: cloudflare

5 days ago I've attached my website on Cloudflare to serve website js and CSS file from here. but didn't show right now. The Cloudflare showing domain is active.

Please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: my website is https://www.findtoptenranks.com

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to check the URI is served by Cloudflare or not.
Check the HTTP(S) response header to see if server is identified as Cloudflare and the existence of [_cfduid cookies](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170156-What-does-the-Cloudflare-cfduid-cookie-do-) in the response header.

```
curl -svo /dev/null https://www.findtoptenranks.com 2>&1 | grep "server:"
< server: cloudflare
```

You can use online benchmarking tools like WebPageTest to measure the performance of your website. I can see that your site have almost 68% of static assets cached by Cloudflare, try to consider moving the external resources to your server so that Cloudflare can cache them as well.

```
Page Weight  #   Size       %
--------------  --  ---------  -------
Cache HIT       62  707.50KB   67.91%
NOT Caching     3   22.56KB    2.17%
External        19  311.72KB   29.92%
Total           84  1041.78KB  100.00%
```